# FlashDevelop build error for Flash Builder project: error in mx_managers_SystemManager.as

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I have a Flash Builder project with an ant build.xml. I built the project with the ant file in Eclipse. Then I imported the project in FlashDevelop. I am getting error in file SystemManager.as! The name of my project is loadtest. In the project loadtest.swf got created, and inside it I could see the reference to _loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as in project explorer. But clicking on it is doing nothing.

I did some search online and found that SystemManager is in mx.manager package of Adobe Flex. I am using Flex 4.6 SDK for this project.

I am unable to understand the error. Is it anything to do with the Flex SDK version? Or, is it anything to do with the Build I did in Eclipse? Or, the reason is that I opened it in FlashDevelop instead of Adobe Flash Builder?

Here is the console output:

```
Running process: C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "D:\Documents\intern\khoa\LOADTEST\loadTestClient\loadTestClient.as3proj" -ipc ac5a2512-1c5d-4dac-913c-de40b01f8d15 -version "4.6.0; 3.1" -compiler "C:\Users\Kajari_G\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\flexsdk\4.6.0" -notrace -library "C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Library"
Building loadTestClient
mxmlc -load-config+=obj\loadTestClientConfig.xml -incremental=true -swf-version=9 -compatibility-version=3 -locale en_US -default-background-color #FFFFFF -o obj\loadTestClient635446913648564685
Incremental compile of 1
 Loading configuration file C:\Users\Kajari_G\AppData\Local\FlashDevelop\Apps\flexsdk\4.6.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml
Loading configuration file D:\Documents\intern\khoa\LOADTEST\loadTestClient\obj\loadTestClientConfig.xml
Updated: D:\Documents\intern\khoa\LOADTEST\loadTestClient\src\functions.as
Files changed: 1 Files affected: 175
_loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(95): col: 40 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Array.
    private var _allowDomainParameters:Vector.<Array>;
                                       ^
_loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(100): col: 48 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Array.
    private var _allowInsecureDomainParameters:Vector.<Array>;
                                               ^
_loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(131): col: 42 Error: Access of undefined property Array.
            _allowDomainParameters = new Vector.<Array>();
                                         ^
_loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(155): col: 50 Error: Access of undefined property Array.
            _allowInsecureDomainParameters = new Vector.<Array>();
                                                 ^
_loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(7): col: 25 Error: Definition flash.text.engine:TextBlock could not be found.
import flash.text.engine.TextBlock;
                        ^
_loadtest_mx_managers_SystemManager.as(8): col: 25 Error: Definition flash.text.engine:TextLine could not be found.
import flash.text.engine.TextLine;
                        ^
Build halted with errors (fcsh).
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I had to change the target Flex SDK to 3.6a. Previously it was Flex SDK 4.6.

Thanks to the following forum post:

```
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=8960&view=next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is problem of because your project is not capable to find mx.manager.SystemManager. Your selected version of sdk is not supporting. You can switch your sdk or include playerglobal.swc. choice is upto you.